# Dynamics CRM 2013: How to check whether an contact already got a connection to a record?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

we've got multiple companys (entity "Account") in our Dynamics CRM 2013, which can have multiple employees (entity "Contact"). We connect them (entity: "Connection") together.

One employee can work for multiple companys at the same time.

It should be possible to **connect an employee to the same company again, if the field "EffectiveEnd" (entity "Connection") is not empty.**

I wanted to use the SDK this way:

If field "Record1" contains data, catch all records in the entity "connection", where the Name is identical. 
This way, I could check in the next step, whether the field "EffectiveEnd" contains data and if not, break the function.
I used the following code:

```
function validateContact() {
if (Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("record2id").getValue() != null) {
    var primaryContactName = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("record2id").getValue()[0].name;

    var paramType = "Connection";

    var paramOptions = "$select=EffectiveStart&$filter=Record2RoleId/Name eq " + primaryContactName + "";

    var strQueryResult = SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords(paramType, paramOptions, retrieveSuccessCallback, errorHandler, retrieveComplete);
} 
else {
//     alert("empty");
    return;
  }
}
```

but I'm getting error 400 (own translation at the error messages):

```
var paramOptions = "$select=EffectiveStart&$filter=Record2RoleId/Name eq " + primaryContactName + "";
```

results in

Error: 400: Bad Request: No Property 'Schulz' in type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' at position 22.

and

```
var paramOptions = "$select=EffectiveStart&$filter=Record2RoleId/FullName eq " + primaryContactName + "";
```

results in

Error: 400: Bad Request: No property 'FullName' in type 'Microsoft.Crm.Metadata.ComplexTypeinstance'1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXXXX]]' at position 14.

Thanks in advance!

:e Typos

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords is the same function demonstrated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg985387(v=crm.7).aspx#sample_/Scripts/SDK.REST.js).

In which case you are effectively doing this:

`SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("Connection",  "$select=EffectiveStart&$filter=Record2RoleId/FullName eq " + primaryContactName + ", ...);`

In which case you would seem to be trying to query the connection entity using fields that doesnt exist on the connection entity. Fullname is a contact field.

You will need to join from the connection entity to the contact entity via the lookup (`EntityReference`) fields.

[Retrieve related entities by expanding navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334767.aspx#bkmk_expandRelated)

> Use the $expand system query option in the navigation properties to
>   control what data from related entities is returned.
>
> `[Organization URI]/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name&$expand=primarycontactid($select=contactid,fullname)`

Or, you could change to query directly onto the contact entity. `var paramType = "contact";`